# Renewing passport in India and coming back to the USA with new renewed passport?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, passport-renewals, us-permanent-residents

I am an Indian citizen living in the USA with a Green Card. I plan to visit India and renew my passport, and then come back to the USA with my new passport on the same round-trip ticket from the USA. Is it OK to travel out of the USA on my old passport and come back to the USA on a new passport (renewed) with the same airline (I mean same ticket)? Would the airline cause me any issue on my return back to the USA?

Comment: The Green Card should suffice for admittance to the USA even  without _any_ passport. (That may not work for certain transit airports.)

Answer (score 4):

No they won't. Just keep your cancelled passport with you too in case they ask for it.

Comment: @credit Please accept as the final answer (click on the tick mark) if you are satisfied. For members voting to delete, I invite you to put up a different answer.

Comment: @TheLastWord There are no votes to delete on this answer.